# Remove ce-wrappers of fluid cObject

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

I masked(mask-extension) a couple of plug-ins. When the image is generated in the template, it is always wrapped in following divs:

```
<div id="c63" class="frame frame-default frame-type-image frame-layout-0">
<div class="ce-image ce-center ce-above">
    <div class="ce-gallery" data-ce-columns="1" data-ce-images="1">
        <div class="ce-outer">
            <div class="ce-inner">
                <div class="ce-row">
                    <div class="ce-column">
                        <figure class="image"><img class="image-embed-item"
                                                   src="fileadmin/user_upload/bla" width="975"
                                                   height="678" alt=""></figure>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to remove all those wrappers? I simply want to have the image.

Sidenotes:
1. f:image does not work, I cannot access the proper uid for it to show. (This is perhaps an issue with mask)
2. I cannot find the tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap > in my typoScript, as I do not know where mask puts it. It is neither in the netup.ts nor in the NewContentElementWizard.ts

Answer (score 2):

You need to overwrite the `fluid_styled_content` partial in `Resources/Private/Partials/Media/Gallery.html`.

How to overwrite, you can read here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/fluid_styled_content/8.7/Configuration/OverridingFluidTemplates/